# Check if certain Javascript object key has exact nested values and then update specific nested value

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript object that can have either none, one, or multiple keys. Then each key has a nested value.

Example

```
cart = {
    "98eb9514-f403-4d08-b5f7-dd6a5ec013cb": {
        "quantity": 1,
        "FirstName": "John",
        "LastName": "Lewis"
    },
    "92ef2918-6bc2-4f3b-b9b3-acf6ebe74b1f": {
        "quantity": 1,
        "FirstName": "Matthew",
        "LastName": "Smith"
    }
}
```

I need to check if a key has an exact nested value. If it does, then I need to add 1 to the quantity for that exact key with that exact nested value.

I am able to check if an exact key with that exact nested value exist by doing:

```
if (cart.hasOwnProperty(productId) &&
    cart[productId]["quantity"] >= 1 &&
    cart[productId]["FirstName"] == FirstName &&
    cart[productId]["LastName"] == LastName) {
    console.log('add one to qty somehow...')
}
```

However, this seems very inefficient and then I can't even figure out a way to add one to the quantity for just that exact key with that exact nested value.

If it is not clear, my question comes down to this:
How do I check if a key with an exact nested value exist, and if it does, how do I add 1 to the quantity for that same exact key/nested value.

Been working on this for a day and half. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You're essentially asking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects). You're doing it the technically correct way; in your situation you would probably be able to use the simpler "compare JSON.stringified versions of the object" method instead.

Comment: Why not use one of any libraries that comes with a "deep equals" function? (If you're working in Node: good news, you already get `assert` for free, it's part of the Node API) That's been a solved problem for a long time now, no need to roll your own code here =)

Comment: What do you mean by "exact nested value"? A certain set of properties with a certain value? If that's the case, then there is pretty much no way around comparing each and every property.  There might be some libraries implementing a generic deep object equality (`==` won't work!) But they are just hiding the same concept behind a function call

Comment: `cart[productId].quantity++` would add one to the quantity prop in the nested value.

Comment: @DanielBeck comparing stringified objects as equality check may be quite dangerous, as the result of a stringify *may* depend on the order in which the properties are inserted in the object. (Depending on the particular runtime)

Comment: If you want schema validation, consider using [joi](https://joi.dev/api/).

Comment: Strictly speaking @derpischer is correct; as far as I known current JS runtimes all have a deterministic JSON.stringify, but it's still probably not a great idea to depend on it, I probably shouldn't have suggested it.

Comment: Except you can _force_ the ordering to be the same: JSON.stringify doesn't take one argument, [it takes three](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#syntax), and the second argument is what allows this solution to work perfectly fine, every single time. The `replacer` argument for JSON.stringify is a rarely talked about powerhouse for object rewriting/analysis. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69587784/740553

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```js
const cart = {
"98eb9514-f403-4d08-b5f7-dd6a5ec013cb":{"quantity":1,"FirstName":"John", "LastName":"Lewis"},
"92ef2918-6bc2-4f3b-b9b3-acf6ebe74b1f":{"quantity":1,"FirstName":"Matthew", "LastName":"Smith"}
}
const productId = "92ef2918-6bc2-4f3b-b9b3-acf6ebe74b1f";
const firstName = "Matthew";
const lastName = "Smith";
const quantity = 1;

const cartItem = cart[productId];

if(typeof cartItem !== "undefined" && cartItem.FirstName === firstName && cartItem.LastName === lastName && cartItem.quantity >= 1) {
  cartItem.quantity += 1;
};

console.log(cart);
```

Once you have a handle on the intended cart property, you can simply increment its `quantity` property.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let cart = {
    "98eb9514-f403-4d08-b5f7-dd6a5ec013cb": {
        "quantity": 1,
        "FirstName": "John",
        "LastName": "Lewis"
    },
    "92ef2918-6bc2-4f3b-b9b3-acf6ebe74b1f": {
        "quantity": 1,
        "FirstName": "Matthew",
        "LastName": "Smith"
    }
}
let productId = '98eb9514-f403-4d08-b5f7-dd6a5ec013cb'; // any product key
let valueToMAtch = 1; // any value to match

let productKey = Object.keys(cart).find((key) => key === productId);
Object.entries(cart[productKey] || {}).forEach(([key, value]) => { // || {} allows undefined handing if no product is found
    if (value === valueToMAtch) {
        cart[productKey][key] += 1; // adding one
    }
});

console.log(cart); // result
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're comparing thousands of records to thousands of other records, might want to pack it up somehow - the intent here, though, is it to de-dupe?

If so, you could try something like...

```
var cartCounter = {};
for (var itemKey in cart) {
 var item = cart[itemKey];
 var key = item.FirstName + "|" + item.LastName;
 if (!cartCounter[key]) {
  cartCounter[key] = item;
 } else {
  cartCounter[key].quantity++;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need deep equality based on enumerable properties only (that is: the values that you get when you use `for...of`, or `Object.keys`, etc.) then you can determine equality based on the JSON serialization of those objects, ***provided you force key sorting***, using the [rarely talked about `replacer` argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#syntax) for `JSON.stringify()`.

This is an incredibly powerful feature of the JSON serialization process, and we can write a simple function that will guarantee any object we pass in will always serialize to the same JSON string, regardless of key ordering at any depth:

```js
function sortedObjectKeys(_, data) {
  // Ignore primitives.
  if (data === null) return null;
  if (typeof data !== "object") return data;

  // Also ignore iterables, which are type "object" but
  // should not be sorted because [1,2,3] is not [1,3,2].
  if (data.__proto__[Symbol.iterator]) return data;

  // Then sort the object keys and yield a new object with that
  // ordering enforced by key insertion.
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data).sort());
}
```

We can now perform a deep equality test using string equality:

```js
function deepEqual(o1, o2) {
  const s1 = JSON.stringify(o1, sortedObjectKeys);
  const s2 = JSON.stringify(o2, sortedObjectKeys);
  return s1 === s2;
}
```